# How to find p value when comparing small amounts of data?

Tags: r, p-value, biostatistics, small-sample

I am comparing shorebird populations and need to determine if they are statistically different across two beaches. I ran a Kruskal Wallis test on another set of data and got good p values but since my data for the birds is very low? I don't know how to find the data I need or if I'm even doing the right thing. I'd appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset, above is R code.)

Answer (score 0):

The values of bird counts by species and beach* are a simple [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table), for which several tests can be applied. The classic is the [chi-square test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) of independence. See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2391/28500) and [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/178854/28500) as entries into further discussion on this site about contingency table analysis.

In your situation, with 3 species out of 6 specific to one beach and 2 to the other, it won't matter much what test you use despite the low values of some of the counts.

---

*The other columns in the table are the total numbers of birds and the total numbers of observed species for the 2 beaches.