# Multiple comparison with two different tests: Fisher exact test and Chi2

Tags: chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, fishers-exact-test

I have a set of genes from particular species. Metagenome samples were mapped to this database of genes' sequences. As a result I had a presence/absence matrix for all the possible genes and species, which looked like this:

```
         sample_1 | sample_2 | ... | sample_n

gene_1       1         0                1          
gene_2       1         1                0
...
gene_m       0         0                0
```

0 stands for absence of gene, 1 for presence

Some of the samples were taken from patients with particular disease, some from healthy people. So they are divided into two groups: case and control
For each gene I hypothesize that it has same proportion of presence/absence for both case and control groups. Alternative is that number of genes which are present and absent is unevenly distributed. I assume I can generate contingency tables for each gene:

```
               Case   |   Control
               -------+-------
Gene_i present    a   |   b
Gene_i absent     c   |   d
```

I thought I can use FET or Chi2 test depending on number of observations in cells. If minimum is less than 10, I use FET. Otherwise Chi2.

I have doubts whether assumption about marginal totals for FET is met, because there's no fixed number of times gene is present.

If minimum value in a table is more than 10, Chi2 test is performed, otherwise Fisher exact test is performed.
Is it appropriate to use one procedure for p-values adjustment if they are obtained in different tests or p-values from these 2 tests should be treated separately?

Comment: I added more information about what I'm trying to do. It has nothing to do with GWAS

Comment: I've updated the answer, but it's essentially the same. Think about point 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you provided here are some factors you'd need to think about:

- What are the features and assumptions of Fisher's test? Are you fine with those? Take a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153044/fishers-exact-test-vs-chi-squared), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test), and [this](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/statistics/index.htm?stat_chi-square_or_fishers_test.htm)
- Do you know that if you use Fisher's test for large number it most often get's approximated using a test like Chi2 without people knowing it?

So, given the last item in the list, the answer to your question is rather clear.